# A hot bar under tap water loses its heat by?

Tags: thermodynamics

In my book,it is given that hot bar placed under a running tap loses heat by conduction. My question is that why it can't be convection as the movement of water molecules is involved.

Comment: I think the term convection is restricted to air maybe.

Comment: Wikipedia: " Sometimes the term "convection" is used to refer specifically to "free heat convection" (natural heat convection) which is due to temperature-induced differences in buoyancy, as opposed to "forced heat convection" where forces other than buoyancy (such as pump or fan) move the fluid. However, in mechanics the correct use of the word "convection" is the general sense, and different types of convection should be qualified for clarity. "--- So this might be a problem of different definitions. Yet in any definition it applies to any gas, liquid or similar

Answer (score 3):

The cooling here obviously involves the movement of material, so, by definition, it is a form of convection and probably could be classified as a forced convection.

Of course, some thermal conduction also takes place, for instance, carrying heat from the bulk of the bar to its surface and from its surface to the passing water, but the dominant cooling mechanism here is due to the constant supply of cool water and therefore, it definitely involves convection.

Comment: I'm not sure I would call it dominant (since the heat conduction from the bar matches the heat flow away by convection).  But it certainly is limiting.